# VIEW e JOIN, retornar o produto, e o valor com a data mais recente!

Tags: mysql, sql

**Possuo a seguintes tabelas que criei.**

```
CREATE TABLE produto (
  codigo        INT UNSIGNED      NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  nome          VARCHAR(128)      NOT NULL,
  url           VARCHAR(255)      NOT NULL,
  qde_min       SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  prazo_entrega TINYINT UNSIGNED  NOT NULL,
  descricao     VARCHAR(1000)              DEFAULT NULL,
  status TINYINT(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (codigo)
);

CREATE TABLE produto_preco (
  valor       DOUBLE(9, 2) NOT NULL,
  cod_produto INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  data        DATETIME     NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (cod_produto) REFERENCES produto (codigo)
);
```

Eu preciso que ao executar a VIEW, retorne todos os produtos com seu ultimo valor. Ou seja o valor que tem a data mais recente do produto.

Quando consulto minha VIEW, os dados são retornados da seguinte maneira:

> SELECT * FROM view_site_produtos;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

SQL da VIEW:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_site_produtos AS
SELECT p.codigo, p.nome, p.url, pp.valor FROM produto p
  LEFT JOIN produto_preco pp ON p.codigo = pp.cod_produto
GROUP BY p.codigo;
```

Já tentei com ORDER BY, e também não deu!

**Notem que o produto Laranja está com valor 20**

> SELECT * FROM produto_preco;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Sendo que o valor correto e 18, pois tem a data mais recente!**

Alguma tem uma sugestão, ou solução de como eu posso fazer isso funcionar?

Comment: não sei se entendi bem, mas quando você tentou ordenar, estava tipo `order by data desc`?

Comment: Tentei ASC e DESC, e não adiantou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como a necessidade era buscar o preço do produto com a maior data, é somente fazer um sub-select que busque a maior data na tabela `produto_preco` e filtrar a o campo `data`.

#### Exemplo

Dados tabela `produto`

```
| codigo |    nome |
|--------|---------|
|      1 | Laranja |
|      2 |    Maça |
|      3 |    Kiwi |
|      4 |    Pera |
```

Dados da tabela `produto_preco`

```
| valor | cod_produto |                 data |
|-------|-------------|----------------------|
|    30 |           3 | 2018-02-18T17:23:12Z |
|  4.44 |           2 | 2018-02-14T17:23:12Z |
|    18 |           1 | 2018-02-22T17:23:12Z |
|    17 |           1 | 2018-02-17T17:23:12Z |
|    15 |           1 | 2018-02-14T17:23:12Z |
|    20 |           1 | 2018-02-14T17:23:12Z |
```

Como na pergunta não tem se era para listar somente os produtos que tem preço ou os todos os produtos vou deixar os 2 exemplos.

#### Lista somente produto com preço

No SQL abaixo, está sendo feito o `left join` da tabela `produto` com a tabela `produto_preco`. Mas o comando `pp.data = (select max(data) from produto_preco where cod_produto = p.codigo)` transforma o `left join` em `inner join`.

```
SELECT
  p.codigo, p.nome, pp.valor, pp.data
FROM
  produto p
  LEFT JOIN produto_preco pp ON p.codigo = pp.cod_produto
where
  pp.data = (select max(data) from produto_preco where cod_produto = p.codigo)
```

Resultado do SQL não traz o produto **Pera**.

```
| codigo |    nome | valor |                 data |
|--------|---------|-------|----------------------|
|      3 |    Kiwi |    30 | 2018-02-18T17:23:12Z |
|      2 |    Maça |  4.44 | 2018-02-14T17:23:12Z |
|      1 | Laranja |    18 | 2018-02-22T17:23:12Z |
```

#### Lista todos produto com ou sem preço

No SQL abaixo, está sendo feito o `left join` da tabela `produto` com a tabela `produto_preco`, mas neste exemplo o comando `pp.data = (select max(data) from produto_preco where cod_produto = p.codigo)` está no `left join`, mantendo assim o `left join`.

```
SELECT
  p.codigo, p.nome, pp.valor, pp.data
FROM
  produto p
  LEFT JOIN produto_preco pp ON 
    p.codigo = pp.cod_produto and
    pp.data = (select max(data) from produto_preco where cod_produto = p.codigo)
```

Resultado é todos os produtos, porém nulo no campo `valor` e `data`.

```
| codigo |    nome |  valor |                 data |
|--------|---------|--------|----------------------|
|      3 |    Kiwi |     30 | 2018-02-18T17:23:12Z |
|      2 |    Maça |   4.44 | 2018-02-14T17:23:12Z |
|      1 | Laranja |     18 | 2018-02-22T17:23:12Z |
|      4 |    Pera | (null) |               (null) |
```

#### Examplo prático

Somente produtos com preço

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7e803/16

Com todos os produtos

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fd7de9/12

Comment: Resolveu, muito obrigado :) Agora aprendi que da para passar valor de select no Sub-select!

Comment: Acho que seria bom explicar o que você fez, até para que o @AndréFelipe entenda.

Comment: Digo, o Marlon explicar a resposta.

Comment: @GiulianaBezerra explicado e detalhado a resposta

Comment: @AndréFelipe explicado e detalhado a resposta

Answer (score 0):

Tente fazer o SQL da View assim:

```
    SELECT p.codigo
         , p.nome
         , p.url
         , pp.valor 
      FROM produto p
      LEFT JOIN produto_preco pp ON p.codigo = pp.cod_produto
     WHERE pp.data = (SELECT MAX(data) 
                        FROM produto_preco 
                       WHERE produto_preco.codigo = p.codigo)
  GROUP BY p.codigo;
```